# React app that receives data via an AJAX requests, display the data and makes it searchable

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have recently started using React and wish to know if my code adheres to the React coding style, whether I am following the same approach towards solving any problem and is there any way I can make the code better.

```
var React = require('react');
var Bootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
var xhr = require('superagent');
var Input = Bootstrap.Input;
var Panel = Bootstrap.Panel;

var Polls;
var View = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selectedPoll: '',
            query: ''
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var self = this;
        xhr.get('/polls').end(function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                Polls = res.body;
                if(self.isMounted()){
                    self.setState({
                        selectedPoll: res.body,
                        query: ''
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },
    _onchange: function(value) {
        var result = [];
        (Polls).map(function(val) {
            if(val.uuid.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || val.question_text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                result.push(val);
            }
        });
        this.setState({
            query: value,
            selectedPoll: result
        });
    },
    render:function() {
        return (
            <div id="Container">
                <div id="Sidebar">
                    <SearchBar change={this._onchange} val={this.state.query} />
                        <PollList data={this.state.selectedPoll} />
                </div>
                <div id="PollWindow">
                    <PollView />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    doSearch: function(e) {
        this.props.change(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Input type="text" value={this.props.val} onChange={this.doSearch} />
        )
    }
});

var PollList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var arr = [];
        if(this.props.data !== ''){
            this.props.data.map(function(value) {
                var head = value.uuid;
                var body = value.question_text;
                arr.push(<div key={head}><Panel header={head} key={head}>{body}</Panel></div>);
            });
        }
        return (
            <div>{arr}</div>
        );
    }   
});

var PollView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>Dummy space</p>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = View;
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, 01bit. Hope you enjoy the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty idomatic :) the one major thing you might want to do is make use of `propTypes` to more explicitly define your Component API's. [PropTypes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) help set expections for what values should/can be.

For instance in `SearchBar` your `doSearch()` method looks like

```
this.props.change(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
```

There is an implicit assumption that `onChange` is never going to be null, and that it's a function. You can codify that (and guard against dumb mistakes) by adding

```
propTypes: {
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

alternatively you can leave off: `isRequired` and provide a default value for `onChange` (perhaps a noop function).

#### In PollList

this line is odd (you also do this in `_onChange` of View):

```
this.props.data.map(function(value) {
   var head = value.uuid;
   var body = value.question_text;
   arr.push(<div key={head}><Panel header={head} key={head}>{body}</Panel></div>);
});
```

`.map()` already returns a new array so there is no need to push into the `arr` either just return the child elements or use a `forEach()`